What else happened in Jewish history on Pesach
I know that many other monumental occasions occurred to happen on Pesach, specifically the first day eg; the birth of Yitzchak, Eisav selling the birthright to Yaakov, parts of the Purim story. Are there other ones also?

https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Nirtzah%2C_Zevach_Pesach.3?lang=bi
